# User unauthorized while making ajax call - Django

Tags: django, ajax

I want to get user data through ajax call but `request.user.is_authenticated` gives `False` hence unauthorized.

Few points to notice:

1. User is logged in successfully.
2. csrf token is also passed in ajax request.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I have used below code to get it:

> Ajax

```
function getUserData(user_id) {
    console.log(getCookie("csrftoken"));
    $.ajax({
        url: new URL(`http://localhost:8000/user/${user_id}`),
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
        },
        success: function (result) {
            let data = result;    
        }
    })
}
```

> views.py

```
def getUserData(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        print("check User", user_id)
        print("IS auth: ", request.user)
        if user_id and request.user.is_authenticated: # request.user.is_authenticated = False
            table_data = []
            return JsonResponse(table_data )
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
```

> urls.py

```
path('user/<int:user_id>',views.getUserData,name="getUserData" ),
```